# The number of imaginary quadratic fields of class number 3 is finite ??

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

I read here

[The primes $p$ of the form $p = -(4a^3 + 27b^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185261/the-primes-p-of-the-form-p-4a3-27b2)

that

"  It is known that the number of imaginary quadratic fields of class number 3 is finite. "

But the links did not show it.

And I know many class number questions are open for quadratic fields.

So is that claim correct ?

Reference or proof ?

Comment: See, e.g., https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01517-5/S0025-5718-03-01517-5.pdf

Comment: More generally, Gauss's conjecture that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ goes to $\infty$ as $d\to-\infty$ was proven by Heilbronn in 1934, and implies that there are only finitely many imaginary quadratic number fields with any given class number. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_problem?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks.

Comment: http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

Comment: Possibly more shelf-stable information for the future: the papers cited in the comments above are M. Watkins, "Class numbers of imaginary quadratic fields," in Math. Comp. 73 (2004), 907-938, https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-03-01517-5 and K. Williams & R. Hudson, "Representation of primes by the principal form of discriminant -D when the classnumber h(-D) is 3," in Acta Arithmetica 57 (1991), 131-153, https://doi.org/10.4064/aa-57-2-131-153 (and the second link even leads to a nicer-looking PDF) :)

Comment: @leslietownes those are the same two links from the other 2 ? But thanks