# All number fields with absolute value of discriminant $\le 20$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

> I need to find all number fields with absolute value of discriminant $\le 20$.

Using Minkovsky's theorem I understood that it should be quadric or cubic extension. The case of quadric is very easy. As for cubic case I understood that it should have 2 complex embeddings and his ideal class group should be trivial. But I don't know to how find all of them.

Comment: Is there a lower bound on the discriminant?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question. I need the module of discriminant $\le 20$

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume you mean that the absolute value of the discriminant has to be $\le 20$. You seem happy with the quadratic case, and have correctly narrowed down the cubic fields to complex cubic fields.

**Hint**. The trick here is that the smallest value the discriminant of a cubic field can take (in absolute value) is $23$, namely $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-x^2+1)$ whose discriminant is $-23$, so there are in fact **no** cubic fields of discriminant $|\Delta|\le 20$.

Comment: How can it be proved? It's not obviously for me, that the smallest absolute value of discriminant of cubic field is $23$.

Comment: @Sasha How much do you know about the form a cubic field can take, and the relation between the discriminant of the cubic defining the field and the discriminant of the number field itself? That if $K=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-ax+b)=\mathbb{Q}(\vartheta)$, then $\text{disc}(x^3-ax+b)=4a^3-27b^2=[\mathcal{O}_K:\mathbb{Z}[\vartheta]]^2 \Delta_K$? Minkowski's bound says that $|\Delta_K|\ge 13$, and Stickelberger's theorem says that $\Delta_K\equiv 0,1$ (mod $4$). Can you rule out any of the possibilities?

Comment: I thought about Stickelberger's theorem today. Also it should be complex cubic field, it implies  $|\Delta|\le 0%. So there're 4 possibilities $ \Delta  = -15,-16,-19,-20.$ I knew this relation between discriminants, but I don't know how it can help me.

Answer (score 3):

As the OP has rightfully seen, it remains to exclude the possibilities $\Delta_K=-15,-16,-19,-20$ for a cubic number field $K$.

We can use class field theory to do this. For example, the cases $-15$ and $-19$ are excluded since they are squarefree and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-15})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-19})$ have class numbers not divisible by three (they are $2$ and $1$ respectively). For the details see my answer on this question

[Hilbert class field of a quadratic field whose class number is 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184423/hilbert-class-field-of-a-quadratic-field-whose-class-number-is-3)

A small modification of the proof in the link also settles the case $-16$: if $\Delta_K=-16$ occurs for a cubic number field $K$ then only $2$ ramifies in $K$ and is in fact wildly ramified, since total ramification would result in $\mathrm{ord}_2(\Delta_K)=2$. But then by the same argument we see that the normal closure $N$ of $K$ yields an unramified Abelian extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-16})=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ of degree $3$, which cannot happen as $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ has class number $1$.

Finally, suppose that $\Delta_K=-20$ for a cubic number field $K$ and let $N$ be its normal closure. As with the previous arguments, since $\mathrm{ord}_5(\Delta_K)=1$ we have non-total ramification of $5$ in $K$, so that $N/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is unramified over the prime of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ over $5$. 
Now if $2$ is also non-totally ramified (i.e. wildly ramified) we again see that $N/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ is an unramified Abelian extension, which cannot happen as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ has class number $2$.
If $2$ is totally ramified in $K$ then we see that the unique prime $\mathfrak{p}=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ lying over $2$ ramifies in $N$, and since this ramification is tame (and also the only ramification) we would get that the Abelian extension $N/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ has conductor $\mathfrak{p}$, so that $N$ would be contained in the ray class field $H_{\mathfrak{p}}$ of $\mathfrak{p}$. However we have the exact sequence 
$$
0 \to (\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p})^{*}/\mathrm{im}[\mathcal{O}^{*}]\to Cl_{\mathfrak{p}}\to Cl_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})}\to 0,
$$
for the ray class group $Cl_{\mathfrak{p}}$, which implies that $[H_{\mathfrak{p}}:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})]=2$, which is a contradiction as $[N:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})]=3$.